# How to reset a radio button group to a specific value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one set of radio buttons for which I'm using ng-repeat to display.  I have the last radio button selected by default (ng-checked="$last"):

```
Status: <span ng-repeat="button in statusList">
    <input type="radio" name="status" ng-model="selectedStatus" value="{{button.value}}" ng-checked="$last"/>{{button.name}}</span>
```

My "statusList" is as follows:

```
$scope.statusList = [
   {"name": "Active", "value": "active"},
   {"name": "Inactive", "value": "inactive"},
   {"name": "Either", "value": "either"}
];
```

It works as-is, however, I'd also like to have a reset/clear form button that selects the last radio button again regardless of what the user selected and I'm having trouble getting Angular to do that.  Code examples I've seen so far just unselect all the radio buttons instead of returning to the default $last one.  My clear form method is as follows (other elements in the form removed):

```
$scope.clearSearchData = function() {
    $scope.selectedStatus = "either";
    $scope.MyForm.$setPristine();
};
```

The first time I press the Clear button, the above code works in resetting the selected button to the last one (or another radio button if I hardcode a different value), however subsequent times have no effect, keeping whatever button the user last pressed still active. Other form elements are continually reset each time I hit the clear button, I'm just having trouble getting the radio buttons to work.  (Using Chrome if it matters.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ng-value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) together with `ng-model` for the `selectedStatus` , since `ng-checked` on radio buttons only works the first time as default value,

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out working with the AngularJS sample: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

First, I should not use ng-checked to select one of the radio buttons, instead in the controller I should just set the ng-model value to the "value" property of the button I want selected.  Second, for the model, I need to put the "selectedStatus" value that holds the selected radio button value in a JavaScript object, for some reason I can't use a scalar:

```
$scope.radio = {
    selectedStatus : "either"
};
```

instead of

```
$scope.selectedStatus : "either"
```

Finally, I didn't need to use the ng-value property as I'm using static values from the ng-repeat to set the value of each button.  However, other users' situations may be different, playing with the AngularJS sample on Plunker can give one a better idea of whether value or ng-value is more appropriate.  Anyway, my updated radio button script:

```
      Status: <span class="radio" ng-repeat="button in statusList">
            <input type="radio" name="status" ng-model="radio.selectedStatus" value="{{button.value}}"/>{{button.name}}
        </span>
```